# Philips Hue dimmer switch detailed manual

Tags: lighting, led, home-automation

I have bought a couple of Philips Hue white sets, including two dimmer switches, and started playing with them and various compatible apps. Normally, a dimmer indicates the command transfer by a green built-in LED. However, After some playing, I noticed that one of the dimmers occasionally shows a red light with the built-in LED. What does it mean? The [Philips user manual](http://www2.meethue.com/de-de/productdetail/philips-hue-dimmer-switch#downloads) only explains how to mount the dimmer to the wall.

P.S. Would be great if someone with high reputation could create a `philips-hue` tag.

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: @Tester101, no. I first Google, and then ask on StackExchange: if I get an answer here, others will benefit from this answer appearing here. If I don't, I will contact Philips and publish the answer here of course.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a manual Philips Hue uses a web based trouble shooter. I can only imagine it's because of constant updates to their system. A printed manual would become obsolete in a matter of months. This is going to be a common trend as our world continues to go more and more online. https://www2.meethue.com/support They also have a YouTube channel with a set of instructional videos but I don't recall exactly what it was called. [image]